# How to get media queries to work with style added by a toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a mobile-menu which is toggled by js code when user clicks the mobile-menu-icon.

The problem I have is: when re-sizing screen from mobile view to large view, the menu is still open.

I used media query to hide the mobile-menu for large screens, but it seems the toggle method added `display:block` on the element and the media query cannot override that.

What's your approach to fix this problem?

Comment: @Negin Basiri you have code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.toggle`, use `.toggleClass("hidden")`. Then you can use CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

When the class is removed, it will get whatever styling is default for the media type.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .mobile-menu { display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: I have used this myself quite a lot. Although not in favour for adding !important but it is the best way imo. You can also use a on resize script but I think this is better.

Comment: The onresize event occurs when the browser window has been resized... After the document is loaded.
It's not the same as a CSS rule that occurs onload like `@media`.

How do you know how he named his menu class ?
Is it even a class ? Maybe an id?
Is the display defined at all ?
You don't know.

Comment: This is just an example. In your media query you set the mobile-menu (whatever the class is) to display: none, and for desktop to display: block;

Comment: SO intends to give answers. Examples can be found with Google.

Comment: No, SO intends to help you on the right path, not to provide solutions.

Comment: Being sure of the "right path" to show before replying may be an idea then. «The BEST skill to learn is the one of NOT replying.»

Comment: Whatever mate, I really don't know what your problem is, I'm trying to help someone. @Negin Basiri did this solve your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113112/discussion-between-wim-mertens-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Comment: Whoops. took time to see the notification. I'm [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113112/discussion-between-wim-mertens-and-louys-patrice-bessette) now.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the same by adding !important to display:none in media query for large screens

Answer (score -1):

Or use a resize script like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 641) {
            $(".mobile-menu").hide();
        }
        else {
        }
    })
```

Comment: I don't understand the down vote?? This is a good solution. As mentioned before: In your media query you set the mobile-menu (whatever the class is) to display: none, and for desktop to display: block;